# What's a good place online to sell a used Mac?

Tags: mac, upgrade, recycle, price

Where can I buy or sell a used iMac online?

**EDIT:**

I have a 21.5" iMac (Core 2 Duo, late 2009) and a MacBook which is about two months old. I'd like to sell both and upgrade.

Comment: Are you looking for something more specifically focused than eBay? That's normally where I start looking.

Comment: @Chops - Yes, more specific than eBay please.

Comment: What country are you from? Anything more focused than eBay is usually relatively region-specific.

Comment: @Chops - USA, but then it's "too specific for StackExchange".

Comment: You might consider Craigslist.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about buying and selling Apple hardware. In addition it can't really be answered because the answer heavily depends on your geographic location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can trade your machine(s) in when you purchase a new one from Apple.  They will reduce your cost for the new machine, certify your old ones and do any repairs necessary, and put them back on the market for others to purchase.

http://www.apple.com/recycling/

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the USA, [gazelle.com](http://gazelle.com) can be a good place, but the prices aren't always great.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of these guys several times previously, but don't have any experience of using them myself. http://www.powermax.com/ I suspect you won't get the best deal if trading in an old machine.